# Can I use the system Touch Bar icons in my app?

Tags: swift, macos, nstouchbar

I am trying to add a "New" button and a "Search" button for my app onto the Touch Bar.  In system apps, these are a plus sign and a magnifying glass, respectively.  Is there a way to use these system icons on my touch bar buttons, such as in UIBarButtonItems?  If not, how can I set a touch bar button's content to be a magnifying glass or plus sign?  I am using Swift.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides many system icons that you can use in your app.
The Human Interface Guidelines has a nice visual reference of all of the icons [available here](https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/touch-bar/touch-bar-icons-and-images/). These can be referenced in your app by using the associated [NSImage.Name](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage.name) constant (also described in the HIG).

As an example, the new and search images can be gotten using:

```
let addImage = NSImage(named: .touchBarAddTemplate)
let searchImage = NSImage(named: .touchBarSearchTemplate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could find those icons in the system files, copy them and use them in your application, but I would not recommend it. They are Apple's intellectual property and you are not allowed to use them for public projects.

You should search on sites like [flaticon.com](http://www.flaticon.com) for similar artworks or create them yourself.